# Is it possible to extract values from namespace to class?

Tags: python

For example values from `args` i can extract like this

```
globals().update(vars(args))
```

Is it possible automatically create same properties fro class? Something like this

```
class SomeClass():
    def __init__(self, args):
        globals().update(vars(args))
        exit(self.location)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you meant you want to update the attributes on the class; you can do so with:

```
class SomeClass():
    def __init__(self, args):
        vars(self).update(vars(args))
```

Demo:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.bar = 'baz'
... 
>>> result = SomeClass(Foo())
>>> result.bar
'baz'
```